# keras i reduced my kernel size and i got smaller ETA is it normal

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

I created this model and i was really mad with Epoch Train Time it was like 10 minute per epoch

```
`model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64,'relu',input_shape=(256,256,3)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=(2,2),padding='same',activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=(2,2),padding='same',activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D())
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=(2,2),padding='same',activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D())
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=(2,2),padding='same',activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D())
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.4))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units=64,activation='relu'))

model.add(Dropout(rate=0.5))
model.add(Dense(units=4,activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='Adam',metrics=['acc'],loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy)`
```

and i changed kernel size to (1,1) and my Estimated Time was reduce is it normal ? and What does the kernel affect on my model ?

i tried a lot of changes on my model but just that affected my model

Answer (score 0):

Filter size represents the amount of pixels taken into account in the convolution process, since less pixels are taken into account with a smaller kernel size, its computationally less expensive.